# using Riemann Theorem for removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

In this sketch of a proof, I do not understand the last step. I know that $z^2g'(z)$ is bounded by 1, so we can use Riemann's Theorem. But why is $a_k=0$ for $k<-1$? How can I derive this? Normally boundness of $f$ in a neighbourhood of a singularity $a$ implies $lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)f(z)=0$. How can I apply this to my case?

Comment: Please note that my proof is not right. I am going to delete it but you need to unaccept it first. The other answers are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at is, $g$ has a derivative at $z=0$ and so is entire.

Comment: Why can you state $a_1=\underset {z\to 0}\lim\frac{z^{3/2}g'(z)}{z}$?

Comment: It's the definition of the derivative of $h$ at $z=0$ which is $a_1$.,

Comment: $z^{3/2}$ cannot be well-defined in a neighborhood of $0$, it requires a branch cut. You cannot write $h(z)$ as a power series at $0$.

Comment: Right. My proof is no good. A fix is just a repeat of the correct answer. I will delete it as soon as the OP unaccepts it.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, $z^2g'(z)$ has a removable singularity at $0.$ Thus $z^2g'(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2 + \cdots$ for $|z|$ small. But we have more: from the given estimate, we actually have $z^2g'(z) \to 0$ as $z\to 0.$ Hence $a_0=0.$

Now divide by $z^2$ to see

$$g'(z) = \frac{a_1}{z} + a_2 + a_3z + \cdots.$$

Integrating about a circle $C$ of small radius centered at $0,$ we get $\int_C g'(z)\,dz = 2\pi i a_1.$ But since $g'$ has an antiderivative in $\{z\ne 0\},$ this integral must be $0.$ Therefore $a_1=0.$ Taking antiderivatives then gives $g(z)$ is a constant plus $a_2z +a_3z^2/2 + \cdots,$ and we are done.

Comment: Do you apply $\int_C g'(z)\,dz = 2\pi i a_1.$ here because of $\int_C \frac{g'(z)}{z^{-1+1}}\,dz = 2\pi i a_1.$ with $n=-1$ or the coefficient $a_1$ at $\frac{a_1}{z}$?

Comment: (+1) this answer is correct, whereas the accepted answer is not.

Answer (score 1):

Laurent series expansion is unique. The fact that $z^{2}g'(z)$ is bounded near $0$ implies that it has  power series expansion and this expansion is also a Laurent series expansion. Hence the two expansions must coincide and the coefficients of negative powers in the original Laurent series expansion must vanish.